# how to print a string vertically in c?

Tags: c, string, printf

Ok the output is supposed to look like this:

```
./a 3 4 8 2  
3  
4  
8  
2
```

This is what I have so far, but I am lost and can only get the first integer to print (we have to use GetInt, which gets the specified integer in the string):

```
int main (int argc, char*argv []){  
   int v;    
   int i;  
   i = 1;  
   v = GetInt(argc, argv, i + 1);  

   if(argc >= 1){  
      printf("%d\n", GetInt(argc, argv, i));  
   }  
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: try using a while loop and incrementing the counter over the arguments that exist.

Comment: how would I do this for infinite arguments?

Comment: @kaity: Fortunately for you, computers don't handle infinite numbers of arguments - they are inherently finite.  You could do 'while (*argv != 0)' for an indefinite (but still finite) number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually seeing your implementation of GetInt, something like this (Assumes C90):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int GetInt( int argc, char* argv[], int i ) {
    /* 
     * you may want to use sscanf, strtol or other functions,
     * but you haven't specified
     */
    return atoi( argv[i] );
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
        printf( "%d\n", GetInt( argc, argv, i ) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
$ ./a.out 3 4 8 2
3
4
8
2
```

Error checking omitted and such. It is an exercise to you to figure out how to deal with non-decimal arguments.

Comment: More idiomatic use of the loop: for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) -- obviously, not initializing i as it is declared.  Alternatively (C99), declare i in the loop as in C++:  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) ...

Comment: Plz do not post code for homework. Just point to the right direction e.g. suggest to use loop.

Comment: @qrdl : whether a question is homework or not is irrelevant - we should still answer it in the most complete way.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to use a for-loop to get each value in turn.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, why do you *have* to use `GetInt()`? It's completely superfluous and not part of a standard library, and unless you wrote it yourself (or in class), I can't imagine ever using it. This is what I would do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
      {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
      }
    return 0;
}
```

I know it doesn't use `GetInt()`, but it's shorter, and you probably *shouldn't* be using `GetInt()` because it's kind of useless. Plus, there's already an `atoi()` function and, if you don't want to use that because it's outdated, a `strtol()` function you can recast as an `int` if you have to.

I'm not citicizing you or anything, I'm just wondering why you're being required to use this superfluous, nonstandard function.

Answer (score 0):

Use printf() in a loop. argc is the number of white space separated arguments in argv[], in the example above, argc = 5.

Comment: argc is actually 5 (4 args + 1 for program name). :)